# Port closed for localhost but open for the remote connections

Tags: networking, firewall, postfix, mail

When I try the folowing command from a remote machine it says port open

```
nmap myserver.com -p 143
```

But when I try the same thing  from a local machine (where the mailserver is installed) it says port closed.

```
nmap localhost -p 143
```

UFW is inactive but when I activate it and add the 143 allow the result is the same.

Btw,

`nmap localhost -p 80` says open

What am I missing?

Comment: please [edit] your question, and provide the exact output of the commands you are running.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like `netstat -ln | grep 143` and pay attention to the IP it's listening on.

If it's listening on 0.0.0.0, there must be some packet filtering interfering.

But if it's a specific IP like 1.2.3.4, you know that's different from 127.0.0.1 (localhost), and that's why your server is not answering.

If you are using IPv6, the corresponging situation may apply.